# I am not able to set manually width and height to 'pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView' view

Tags: android, animated-gif

I have used 'pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView' for gif image. But It takes by default size. If i am try give some width and height than it wont take given size it apper as default.

My xml is :

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="7.4">

                <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
                android:id="@+id/gifImageView2"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/hubcreategif1"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3.0"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_hubmessage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_lbldonthave"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="You don't have a hub history yet."
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colordarkgray"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_strcomeback"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/strcomeback"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colordarkgray"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_17sdp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_onboard"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_22sdp"
                        android:text="@string/strcreateorjoin"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_35sdp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_35sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_2sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_7sdp"
                        android:background="@drawable/dotted_bottom_textview_black"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/strhubdetail"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colordarkgray"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
                        android:text="@string/strhubabort"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_11sdp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:textColor="@color/colordarkgray"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and java class is :

gifImageView = (pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gifImageView2);

nothing else

Comment: post your xml and java class please

Comment: I have edited the question with xml and java code

Comment: ok , so what do you mean with "default size" on screen what do you see?

Comment: It takes the some size and display in every device with same size.

Comment: Firstly your layout_weight is wrong , because 7,4 + 3.0 is 10,4 and not your weight_sum (10) setted in parent , it should be 7,0

Comment: I corrected it. Still It is not working.

Comment: unfortunately without see the real result on the screen i don't understand what is the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width and height by setting the following `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`

This should work:

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="10dp" <-- your width
    android:layout_height="10dp" <-- your height
    android:src="@drawable/src_anim"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_anim" />
```

Comment: It should work But It is not working. My gif is big and with lots of images.

Comment: Can you share more of your xml file?